# Spring MVC multipart/form-data file upload then go to a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I had a working form submit on a jsp that takes some basic info as strings. The controller validates the user inputs and determines if it should go back to the page to display error msg or go to a new page. Then I  modified the form submit to allow users to upload files. The problem is when I return the String in my controller method, it doesn't go to the right jsp pages anymore. It just goes to a blank page with text of "/ad/adAdd3/12345" or "redirect:/ad/adDetail/12345". What am i missing?

jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="ad" method="post" class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" id="add-ad-form" 
    action="?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ad/adAdd3/{categoryId}", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public @ResponseBody String postAdAdd(@RequestParam("categoryId") int categoryID,
        @ModelAttribute("ad") @Valid Ad ad,
        BindingResult aaResult,
        SessionStatus aaStatus, Principal aaPrincipal) {

    if (aaResult.hasErrors()) {

        return "/ad/adAdd3/" + categoryID;
    } else {
        ad = this.caService.saveAd(ad, categoryID,
                ((UserDetailsImpl) ((Authentication) aaPrincipal)
                        .getPrincipal()).getUser());

        aaStatus.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/ad/adDetail/" + ad.getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ResponseBody is the problem. Once I removed it, everything is working now.